# run TreeTagger through Python

Tags: python-3.x, treetagger

I'm new to programming, but I have basics of python 3 and have treetagger installed, and through my command shell I can POS tag files.

However, I have 427 files in a folder I am trying to automatically have opened and run through the Treetagger and I can't quite figure out how to make this happen. My current code is as such:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import re

rootdir = r"/Spanish_(ACTIV-es)_corpus/plain"
```

I want to automatically check through a folder with over 427 files and to have appropriate files be POS tagged

I think this requires some combo of what is below along with code including SUBPROCESS commands to get TreeTagger to do its work, that I absolutely do not understand how to use, but tried to implement from feedback from another question here on stack overflow.

[image: sample code]

How do I get the movie_pos to be the file that treetagger will POS tag as it walks through the files in the folder?

Then:output?? Do I need to have already created 427 separate files for the output, or is there a way to authomatically make the output the a modified title of the input so the output isn't confused. (in the title of the files, is where the metadata is currently stored).

Answer (score 0):

Is using Python a strict requirement for tagging the files ? If not, you can easily achieve it just using the shell, by looping over the files of your folder, running TreeTagger on each, and saving (like you correctly assume is possible) to a file with a different name.

As an example, here's a directory with 3 files:

```
$ ls mydir/
1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
```

With some Spanish text in them.

```
$ cat mydir/1.txt
Esto es una prueba.
```

You can then use

1. the shell's [`find`](http://ss64.com/bash/find.html) command to list all the files you care about (e.g. all the files that end in ".txt"

   `find mydir/ -name "*.txt"`
2. the [`for`](http://ss64.com/bash/for.html) command to loop over `find`'s results (using backquotes ` `), and run TreeTagger over each

   `` $ for i in `find ....`; do tag_command_using_$i; done ``

(the variable `$i`holding the path to each file)

3. the shell's redirect feature (`>`) to redirect TreeTagger's output (which you'd normally see on the screen), to a file that you can name appropriately, using the name of your original file

   `tag_command $i > $i.tagged`

In one line, it looks like this:

```
$ for i in `find mydir/ -name "*.txt"`; do cat $i | cmd/tree-tagger-spanish > $i.tagged; done
```

After it's finished you will have the newly created files in the same folder:

```
$ ls mydir/
1.txt        1.txt.tagged 2.txt        2.txt.tagged 3.txt        3.txt.tagged

$ cat mydir/1.txt.tagged
Esto es ADV esto~es
una ART un
prueba  NC  prueba
.   FS  .
```